# crontab gsutil command executes but no output

Tags: cron, google-cloud-storage, gsutil

```
gsutil cp -r gs://mybucetid/stats/installs/installs_com.appdomain_YYYYMM_overview.csv /home/ubuntu/appstats
```

The above command runs successfully from my terminal. The command copies the statistics file from google cloud to my local directory.

Hence I tried to put the above command in crontab.
below is the line from the crontab

```
30 00 * * * gsutil cp -r gs://mybucetid/stats/installs/installs_com.appdomain_YYYYMM_overview.csv /home/ubuntu/appstats
```

The cron executes on time with no errors (checked in cron log) but the file does not download to the specified location)

Can anybody suggest me, in the crontab, what is missing in the command and why the file is not copied from my google cloud bucket to my specified local directory?

Comment: Can you make sure the `HOME` environment variable is being set? I've seen that be a problem before. I suspect your command is not actually executing successfully.

Comment: The HOME environment variable is not set when running under cron, so if your credentials are in ~/.boto they won't be picked up. Try setting HOME=<your homedir>.

Comment: thank you. the cron is doing the work i need. my gsutil is in root directory, so my cron was not able to execute gsutil command. so i just changed 30 00 * * * ~/gsutil/gsutil cp -r gs://mybucetid/stats/installs/installs_com.appdomain_YYYYMM_overview.csv /home/ubuntu/appstats

Answer (score 0):

**Simple Update** *yyyyMM* **to date formate as shown below**

```
30 00 * * * gsutil cp -r gs://mybucetid/stats/installs/installs_com.appdomain_201710_overview.csv /home/ubuntu/appstats
```